# SQL normalization query

Tags: sql, asp.net, normalization, database-normalization

I am creating a project for employee skill set where the table is `SkillRepo` with columns:

```
EmpID, EmpName, SkillName, SkillProficiency, SkillCategory, Experience, Comments
```

My question is that one user may have many skills. So if I make the `EmpID` as primary key, then how can I add other skills for same user in the same table? I think normalization would be needed here, but I can't figure out how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One table for emp

```
 emp 

  EmpID, EmpName,
```

on for emp_skill

```
emp_skill

    EmpID, SkillName, SkillProficiency, SkillCategory, Experience, Comments
```

Answer (score 2):

You need **two** tables - one for the `Employee`:

```
EmpId (PK), EmpName
```

and a second table `Skills` that defines the skills and is linked to the `Employee` table:

```
SkillId (PK), EmpId (FK to Employee), SkillName, SkillProficiency, SkillCategory, Experience
```

This way, you can have **multiple rows** in `Skills` that all reference the **same employee** (by means of its `EmpId` which is stored in the `Skills` table)